# Is there a way to check the toggle status of an object that has no control_type="CheckBox")

Tags: python, checkbox, automation, pycharm, pywinauto

I'm trying to check the toggle status of a checkbox however it doesn't have a control type "CheckBox".
   `|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Pairings:'    (L299, T1063, R343, B1079) |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pairings:', 'Pairings:Static', 'Static129'] |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Pairings:", control_type="Text") |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | CheckBox - ''    (L343, T1063, R363, B1079) |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['CheckBox12', 'Pairings:CheckBox']`

here is what it tools like via automation spy tool
[image]

[image]

I have other checkboxes and the code I used to check the toggle status is
`element.child_window(auto_id="uxCheckOverComplemented", control_type="CheckBox").get_toggle_state()`

Any recommendation is appreciated.

`element.child_window(auto_id="uxCheckOverComplemented", control_type="CheckBox").get_toggle_state()`

Comment: In automation spy tool the control type is correct, so pywinauto should detect it. Naming for some controls may be confusing a little bit especially typo resistant names which may include neighbor control text. Unfortunately the dump from pywinauto is incomplete and probably it is a dump for another controls. Maybe method `.draw_outline()` can help to detect which control is actually found. Sometimes it looks like brute force attempts. We have py_inspect project, but it is not mature enough yet, and code generation capabilities are not implemented.

Comment: Thank you! all sorted now. What I did was I get the main frame where those objects are located to avoid any ambiguous errors, then used index as my basis. a bit general but it works!

Comment: Great. If you have time, please post your own solution as an answer and accept it (it is OK to accept own answers). It will improve statistics for `pywinauto` tag and tell others that the problem is solved.